# a-frame 1.3.0 and any example on the getting started page has terminal javascript errors that prevent the example from working

Tags: aframe

I am using a-frame, current version 1.3.0

Maybe it's a test of some kind or a right of passage for working with A-Frame.

I am going through the getting started with A-Frame documentation and the Hello World example works great, however, going beyond the simple and adding an extension, like a physics engine, teleport controls etc. and none of it works. I just get a load of errors that THREE."something" is not a constructor or THREE."some method" is not defined.

I am doing nothing other than following the documentation and have not even tried to do anything outside that.

Is this just the way it is and extensions and 3rd party code is just not maintained? or is A-Frame just no longer a thing?

What on earth am I doing wrong? Maybe the documentation is just out of date.

Comment: `or is A-Frame just no longer a thing` - don't you even dare! Afaik [aframe-physics has issues since aframe v`1.2.0`](https://github.com/n5ro/aframe-physics-system/issues/187) . In other cases most probably 3rd party code needs updating. If an example from the docs isn't working I think an [issue like this](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/4971) could be a good place to mention it.

Comment: The 3rd party codes you are using is just not maintained. A-Frame 1.3.0 is working great.

Comment: check out aframe.wiki for up-to-date info. e.g., https://aframe.wiki/en/physics